# Is the "Raise dead" spell subject to augmented summoning?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

My question is simple: does raising the dead with a "raise dead" spell constitute a type of summoning that can be affected by the augment summoning feat?  (Aren't we effectively "summoning" the dead spirit from a different plane?)  I suspect it is not, but want to double-check on behalf of one of my players.

Comment: Well it is a conjuration spell for a start, aside from that - don't know!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No, it does not.

Augment Summoning refers to Conjuration (Summoning) spells only. See the text:

> Each creature you **conjure** with a **summoning** spell

(**emphasis** mine)

They could be more explicit and *state* Conjuration (Summoning), but ultimately it’s pretty clear that this is what they meant. Technically, “summoning” is a particular form of calling another creature or spirit that follows the specific rules given under the Conjuration (Summoning) section of the Magic Overview. *Raise dead* is not a Conjuration (Summoning) spell, it is Conjuration (Healing).

Moreover, this strikes me as a bad idea in any event. Dying shouldn’t be a *good* thing...

Comment: People often gloss over the rules for [Schools of Magic](http://systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicSchools.html), though they're really important to understand!